# Вывод в сущности вложенного списка в EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, entity-framework, codefirst

Я новичок в WebApi и пытаюсь, используя Code First и Entity Framework, создать структуру базы по схеме. Одна из моих задач это создание модели и инициализирование бд тестовыми данными.

Вот моя первая модель.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Объект потребления
namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class ConsumptionObject : Object
    {
        public int SubOrganisationID { get; set; }
        public SubOrganisation SubOrganisation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ElectricityMeteringPoint> ElectricityMeteringPoint { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ElectricitySupplyPoint> ElectricitySupplyPoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Вот вторая.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

//Точка измерения электроенергии
namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class ElectricityMeteringPoint : Point
    {
        public int ConsumptionObjectID { get; set; }
        public ConsumptionObject ConsumptionObject { get; set; }
        public int VoltageTransformerID { get; set; }
        public VoltageTransformer VoltageTransformer { get; set;}
        public int ElectricalTransformerID { get; set; }
        public ElectricalTransformer ElectricalTransformer { get; set; }
        public int ElectricityMeterID { get; set; }
        public ElectricityMeter ElectricityMeter { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MeteringDevice> MeteringDevice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Имея связь один-ко-многим мне нужно сделать АПИ по ConsumptionObject внутри которого будет вложенный список со всеми ElectricityMeteringPoint. Я перечитал уже кучу статей и много чего перепробовал но у меня не выходит, при запросе на ConsumptionObject вложенный ElectricityMeteringPoint всегда null, я не понимаю как его добавить.

Вот мой контекст, там я пытаюсь инициализировать тестовые данные и настроить вывод.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class AppTestContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppTestContext(DbContextOptions<AppTestContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<Organisation> Organisation { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubOrganisation> SubOrganisation { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ConsumptionObject> ConsumptionObject { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ElectricitySupplyPoint> ElectricitySupplyPoint { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MeteringDevice> MeteringDevice { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ElectricityMeteringPoint> ElectricityMeteringPoint { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ElectricityMeter> ElectricityMeter { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ElectricalTransformer> ElectricalTransformer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VoltageTransformer> VoltageTransformer { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ElectricityMeteringPoint>()
                .HasOne(a => a.ElectricalTransformer).WithOne(b => b.ElectricityMeteringPoint)
                .HasForeignKey<ElectricalTransformer>(e => e.ElectricityMeteringPointID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ElectricityMeteringPoint>()
                .HasOne(a => a.ElectricityMeter).WithOne(b => b.ElectricityMeteringPoint)
                .HasForeignKey<ElectricityMeter>(e => e.ElectricityMeteringPointID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ElectricityMeteringPoint>()
                .HasOne(a => a.VoltageTransformer).WithOne(b => b.ElectricityMeteringPoint)
                .HasForeignKey<VoltageTransformer>(e => e.ElectricityMeteringPointID);


            /* Наполнение тестовыми данными */

            //Счетчик электрической энергии
            modelBuilder.Entity<ElectricityMeter>().HasData(
                new ElectricityMeter[] 
                {
                    new ElectricityMeter {ID=1, No="123", Type="A1", VerificationDate=new DateTime(2020, 01, 13), ElectricityMeteringPointID=1},
                    new ElectricityMeter {ID=2, No="456", Type="B1", VerificationDate=new DateTime(2021, 02, 14), ElectricityMeteringPointID=2},
                    new ElectricityMeter {ID=3, No="789", Type="C1", VerificationDate=new DateTime(2022, 03, 15), ElectricityMeteringPointID=3},
                });

            //Точка измерения электроэнергии
            modelBuilder.Entity<ElectricityMeteringPoint>(b =>{
                b.HasData(new ElectricityMeteringPoint[] 
                {
                    new ElectricityMeteringPoint {ID=1, Name="Точка измерения 1", ConsumptionObjectID=1, ElectricityMeterID=1},
                    new ElectricityMeteringPoint {ID=2, Name="Точка измерения 2", ConsumptionObjectID=1, ElectricityMeterID=2},
                    new ElectricityMeteringPoint {ID=3, Name="Точка измерения 3", ConsumptionObjectID=1, ElectricityMeterID=3},
                });
                //b.HasOne(b => b.ConsumptionObject).WithMany(b =>b.ElectricityMeteringPoint).HasForeignKey(e => e.ConsumptionObjectID);
                //b.OwnsOne(b => b.ConsumptionObject).WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ConsumptionObjectID");
            });

            //Объект потребления
            modelBuilder.Entity<ConsumptionObject>(b => 
            {
                b.HasData(new ConsumptionObject[] 
                {
                    new ConsumptionObject {ID=1, Name="ПС 110/10 Весна", Address="Москва"}
                });
                //b.HasMany(g => g.ElectricityMeteringPoint).WithOne(e => e.ConsumptionObject).HasForeignKey(e => e.ConsumptionObjectID);
            
                // b.OwnsMany<ElectricityMeteringPoint>(p => p.ElectricityMeteringPoint, a =>
                // {
                //     a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ConsumptionObjectID");
                //     a.Property<int>("ID");
                //     a.Property<string>("Name");
                //     a.HasKey("ID", "Name");
                // });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

И собственно вот что я получаю когда делаю запрос на *https://localhost:8050/api/ConsumptionObject/1* чтобы я не придумывал.

```
{
    "subOrganisationID": 0,
    "subOrganisation": null,
    "electricityMeteringPoint": null,
    "electricitySupplyPoint": null,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ПС 110/10 Весна",
    "address": "Москва"
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так и как мне получить вложенный список.

Comment: попробуйте почитать про [Загрузку связанных данных](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php)

Comment: @Bald Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2):

Решить проблему помогла загрузка связанных данных. Для этого мне потребовалось немного видоизменить данный блок в контроллере добавив туда Include и FirstOrDefaultAsync.

```
// GET: api/ConsumptionObject/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ConsumptionObject>> GetConsumptionObject(int id)
        {
            var consumptionObject = await _context.ConsumptionObject.Include(b => b.ElectricityMeteringPoint).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ID == id);
            

            if (consumptionObject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return consumptionObject;
        }
```

А также чтобы не было ошибок зацикливания когда одна модель ссылается на другую я установил *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson* и заигнорил некоторые свойства вот таким способом.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

// Объект потребления
namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class ConsumptionObject : Object
    {
        public int SubOrganisationID { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public SubOrganisation SubOrganisation { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ElectricityMeteringPoint> ElectricityMeteringPoint { get; set; } = new List<ElectricityMeteringPoint>();
        public ICollection<ElectricitySupplyPoint> ElectricitySupplyPoint { get; set; } = new List<ElectricitySupplyPoint>();
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

//Точка измерения электроенергии
namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class ElectricityMeteringPoint : Point
    {
        public int ConsumptionObjectID { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ConsumptionObject ConsumptionObject { get; set; }
        public int VoltageTransformerID { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public VoltageTransformer VoltageTransformer { get; set;}
        public int ElectricalTransformerID { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ElectricalTransformer ElectricalTransformer { get; set; }
        public int ElectricityMeterID { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ElectricityMeter ElectricityMeter { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MeteringDevice> MeteringDevice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Я не знаю насколько правильно у меня все получилось но данное решение мне помогло.

Если у вас есть лучшее решение я с удовольствием почитаю. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете по другому спроектировать ваши сущности. Раздробив все на составляющие. Первая сущность ConsumptionObject, вторая сущность ElectricityMeteringPoint. Третью сущность (список) можно не плодить. В сущности ElectricityMeteringPoint, добавляете виртуальное свойство public virtual (типа) ConsumptionObject, с названием, например ConsumObject. Далее этот также добавляем ссылку на Id ConsumptionObject. Для этого нужно добавить свойство например int ConsumObjectId. Так что, в классе ElectricityMeteringPoint, должен быть такой код:

```
public int ConsumObjectId{get; set;};

[ForeignKey("ConsumObjectId")]
public virtual ConsumptionObject ConsumObject {get; set;};
```

Списки ElectricityMeteringPoint, по каждому объекту можно получить формируя соответствующий запрос к БД. Более подробно на примере, аналогичная проблема разбирается [вот здесь](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm_HvURobtaz8GrLaI-iQhhc) Там на примере интернет магазина на ASP.NET Core MVC сначала создается Категория Товара,  а потом создается сущность Товар, которая содержит ссылку на существующую Категорию